# How can I build For-Next-Loop in Change Event?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a sheet with Data.
I want to calculate the difference between date now and the date which are in cells C3:C10. And the results are stored in cells D3:D10.

That part I got it so far.

But if someone manipulates the values in the result cells then the VBA should recalculate those cells and correct the results.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Zeile = 3 To 10
        Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(Zeile, "D") = WorksheetFunction.YearFrac(Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(Zeile, "C"), Date)
        If Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(Zeile, "C") = 0 Then
           Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(Zeile, "D") = ""
        End If
    Next Zeile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is check if the change has been made in `C3:C10`, you can use `Intersect` for that.

Then you should disable events to stop the code triggering itself, use `Application.EnableEvents = False` for that.

Next loop through `Target` in case more than one cell has been changed and perform the required actions/calculations.

Finally re-enable events using `Application.EnableEvents = True`

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Zeile As Long

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C10"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            Zeile = cell.Row
            If Cells(Zeile, "C") <> 0 Then
                Cells(Zeile, "D") = Application.YearFrac(Cells(Zeile, "C").Value, Date)
            Else
                Cells(Zeile, "D") = ""
            End If

        Next cell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
    
End Sub
```

If you want the code to be triggered if a value is changed in either `C3:C10` or `D3:D10` change this,

```vb
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C10"))
```

to this.

```vb
Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C3:D10"))
```

You can also change the range address there if you want to further rows by changing 10.

Comment: If someone clears an intersecting row, the loop will be ~16000 iterations long due to the size of target.cells. It might be better to run the loop like `For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C10")).Cells` to ensure it runs the minimum number of iterations.

Comment: Hi, if I run the code there is an error message. Here is the pic [Link](https://i.ibb.co/LtSnrGZ/Fehlermeldung-VBA.jpg). It is asking for macro to run.

Comment: That's not an error message, its asking you which macro you intended to run. Because you cant run an event by clicking play. You need to *trigger* the event by changing a cell on the page.

Comment: @Credo_Moi You don't run the code manually, it's triggered when you make a change on the relevant sheet. If you change something in the relevant range, i.e. `C3:C10` then the body of the code will be executed.

Comment: @norie Thanks a lot for the provided solution. It is Working!!! But the code is working , when I change the value in column C. My thinking is when someone unintentionally changes the output value in D then the code must rerun and correct the value of the cell in D.